# how to del and add route with c code or object c in macosx

Tags: c, macos, routes

In macosx, an important part if my project is to delete the original route entry , and add the necessary new route to the system. when the project exits, I need to restore the original route table as before.

unlike the linux or windows, the command to delete or add the route is so complex with so many arguments to consider. apart from that, when use the

```
netstat -nr
```

to print the route table, the different presentations of gateway and the flags of each table are troubling me.

so if there are apis to delete and add the route in macosx ,c or object-c ,either appreciated.

All I know that in linux We can use the ioctl plus the SIOCADDRT OR SIOCDELRT to accomplish this ,but mac doesn't support that.

Comment: Well, there must be an interface to do exactly that because how else would `route(8)` do it? So, in order to understand how that works, you're probably better off reading [the source code of the route command itself](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/network_cmds/network_cmds-328/netstat.tproj/route.c).